# .zshrc configuration doesn't set ENABLE_TMUX to true

Tags: zsh, tmux, xubuntu

In my .zshrc, I have
`ENABLE_TMUX="TRUE"`
for one of the lines. This doesn't seem to work, as tmux never launches on a new shell, and the environment variable ENABLE_TMUX is always false when I start a shell. The rest of my zshrc works fine, however. I'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

```
### START TMUX IF ENABLED ABOVE ###
if [ "$ENABLE_TMUX" = "TRUE" ]; then
    # start tmux if not already running
    if [[ ! "$TTY" =~ "/dev/tty" ]]; then
        case $(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=) in
            tmux*|*vscode*|*xterm*|*kdevelop*|*ascii*)
                sleep 0
                ;;
            *)
                tmux
                ;;
        esac
    fi
fi
###
```

This is the function that starts tmux. Not sure what's wrong here, if anything.
I am on Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've just tried it and it works for me, make sure that this function is run at all by adding several `printf`s or `echo`s here and there and if it is that means you do not enter `if` condition at all or enter the first `case` or `tmux` fails to start. Try to run `tmux` in interactive shell first to make sure.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you said that `ENABLE_TMUX` is always FALSE - it means that it has be explicitly set to `FALSE` somewhere before reaching this function as variables do not take FALSE as value implicitly. Try to do `ENABLE_TMUX=TRUE` in the line above `if [ "$ENABLE_TMUX" = "TRUE" ]; then` and it should work.  You could also show your entire `~/.zshrc` if you are not sure what's going on.

Comment: Not sure what's causing it to reset itself before the function, but setting it to true immediately before the function works. I'll dig through my zshrc and try to find what was causing the problem, but this is fine too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ENABLE_TMUX` is not reset at all.

In `.zshrc`, `[[ ! "$TTY" =~ "/dev/tty" ]]` is not true. So no tmux session will be started.